# How can I write a generator in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Usually, I write code like this:

```
//definition
exports.getReply = function * (msg){
    //...
    return reply; 
}
//usage
var msg = yield getReply ('hello');
```

but how can I write and use a generator in and out of an es6 class? I tried this:

```
class Reply{
    *getReply (msg){
        //...
        return reply; 
    }
     *otherFun(){
        this.getReply();  //`this` seem to have no access to `getReply`
    }
}
var Reply = new Reply();
Reply.getReply();   //out of class,how can I get access to `getReply`?
```

I also tried:

```
 class Reply{
      getReply(){
         return function*(msg){
            //...
            return reply;
         }
      }
    }
```

All of these two methods seem to be wrong answers. So how can I write generator functions in a class correctly?

Comment: "All of these two methods seem to be wrong answers" --- what does it mean? You define generator functions in classes the same way the "normal" generator functions.

Comment: @zerkms Can you show an example? It creates a syntax error when I tried that.

Comment: Your code (the class definition in the first example) is syntactically correct and runs without syntax errors.

Comment: You need to use a different variable name, like `var reply = new Reply();`

Comment: @Bergi, this question is NOT a duplicate of the referenced question, this one is about classed and the other is about object literals

Comment: I agree with @DmitryMatveev that this is not a duplicated of said question.
I have flagged this for a moderator, so I can give you a proper answer, which'll fully help you on your way :)

Comment: @DmitryMatveev: Indeed, but the syntax is the same in both. And zermks is very right, OP already uses the correct syntax, something else must be at fault.

Comment: I've found that it's not the way I definite the class that caused the problem. It's the way I use it. Also , I agree with @DmitryMatveev  that this is not a duplicated of said question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Edit: Add more examples.
Your `class` definition is (almost) correct.The error was in instantiation `var Reply = new Reply();`. This tries to redefine variable assigned to class name. Also `generator` function is expected to `yield` something. I elaborated a little OP code to show working example.

```js
class Reply {
  //added for test purpose
  constructor(...args) {
      this.args = args;
    }
    * getReply(msg) {
      for (let arg in this.args) {
        let reply = msg + this.args[arg];
        //generator should yield something
        yield reply;
      }
      //next call returns (yields) {done:true,value:undefined}
    }
    * otherFun() {
      yield this.getReply('Nice to meet you '); //yields Generator object
      yield this.getReply('See you '); //Yes, this can access 
      //next call yields {done:true, value:undefined}
    }
    * evenMore() {
      yield* this.getReply('I miss you '); //yields generator result(s)
      yield* this.getReply('I miss you even more ');
    }
}
//now test what we have
const reply = new Reply('Peter', 'James', 'John');
//let and var here are interchangeable because of Global scope
var r = reply.getReply('Hello ');
var msg = r.next(); //{done:false,value:"..."}
while (!msg.done) {
  console.log(msg.value);
  msg = r.next();
}
var other = reply.otherFun();
var o = other.next(); //{done:false,value:Generator}
while (!o.done) {
  let gen = o.value;
  msg = gen.next();
  while (!msg.done) {
    console.log(msg.value);
    msg = gen.next();
  }
  o = other.next();
}
var more = reply.evenMore();
msg = more.next();
while (!msg.done) {
  console.log(msg.value);
  msg = more.next();
}
//update of 1/12/2019
//more examples
for (let r of reply.getReply('for ')) {
  console.log(r);
}
for (let r of reply.evenMore()) {
  console.log(r);
}
//note that the following doesn't work because of lack of star (*) inside the generator function
for (let r of reply.otherFun()) {
  console.log(r);
}
```

**UPDATE 1/12/2019**

As suggested by @BugBuddy `for..of` loop looks even nicer (But doesn't work in all cases). See updated lines in the snippet.

Comment: Alex, I am wondering why you use `yield this.getReply('Nice to meet you ');`   instead of `yield * this.getReply('Nice to meet you')`.                                      The `getReply` itself **is** a generator function, isn't it ?

Comment: Can you show the use of `for...of` in your example? Wouldn't that result in better code than the while loops?

Comment: @BugBuddy Thank you for suggestion and see updated answer.

Comment: If you are interested, Symbol.iterator is one more thing you could add to your great example: Inside class Reply: `*[Symbol.iterator]() { for (let a of this.args) {yield a;} }`
example use: `for (let arg of reply) { console.log('I came from Symbol.iterator: ' + arg);}`

Comment: Just a note, this does not work statically, i.e. `static * getReply() {}` is invalid, for this case (also works non-statically) use a getter, i.e. `static get getReply() {return *function() {} }`

Answer (score 50):

## TL; DR for confused visitors from Google:

> In Javascript, how do I write a generator function in a class?

```js
class A {
    * values() {
        yield "a value";
        yield* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    }
}
```

is syntactically correct. It works. You’re welcome and now dismissed.

Comment: 

Comment: TypeScript: `public* values() {}`

Answer (score -1):

To add some documentation to the table:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#generator_as_an_object_method

```js
class Foo {
  *generator () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
}

const f = new Foo ();
const gen = f.generator();

console.log(gen.next()); // { value: 1, done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: 3, done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Answer (score -3):

Generators are functions with a `.next()` for getting the `yield`'ed values or you can `yield` a generator function to let it know it doesn't need to "wait" upon encountering a `yield` statement for a `.next` to be called (`reply.getReply().next(fn)`)

Your second piece of code is almost correct:

```
class Reply{
    *getReply (msg){
        //...
        return reply; 
    }
     *otherFun(){
        this.getReply();  //`this` seem to have no access to `getReply`
    }
}
var Reply = new Reply();
Reply.getReply();   //out of class,how can I get access to `getReply`?
```

First of all, please use `const` or `let` when working in ES6 and only use the uppercase variant for classes.
You are trying to overwrite the `class Reply` statement with the `var Reply =` statement, which is not possible since the `Identifier 'Reply'` is already declared.

The answer you are looking for is as followed:
Just like you are doing in the first example, you should `yield` the generator functions, so your could should look like this:

```
class Reply{
    *getReply (msg){
        // yield something here, otherwise you should use a normal function
        return reply;
    }
     *otherFun(){
        const reply = yield this.getReply();  // yield the generator so it does what it needs to and doesn't wait for the .next() to be called on it
        return `${reply} within class ${this.constructor.name}`;
    }
}
const reply = new Reply();
const answer = yield reply.getReply('foo'); 
// getReply is a generator function, so it needs a `yield` or `.next()` to run beyond the first `yield` in the function
```

Comment: "*you should `yield` the generator functions*" - no. The code in your answer yields generators, and you shouldn't do that either. You should `yield*` generators.

Comment: _"You are essentially overwriting the class Reply statement with the var Reply = statement."_ That's not possible. _"const reply = yield this.getReply();"_ Why `const reply = `? _"yield reply.getReply('foo');"_ `yield` outside a generator function?

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean with `yield*`? There is no such thing as `yield*`...? It's `function *something(){}` and `yield`...
@zeroflagL I corrected the overwrite explanation, it'll actually return an error that the `Identifier 'Reply'` already exists.
`const reply = `, because it's a new instance of Reply, so you might not want that to be overwritten bij something else and no, it's not possible to call `yield` to be called outside a generator function, but it is the way to do this.
I'll change the answer to include more code on how to get the return value outside of a generator function

Comment: @CreasolDev Of course there is, look [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) up.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, my apologies, I did not know that, but if it's just the return value he wants, there is no reason to use `yield*`
It would seem more logical to use something like co.wrap, which'll return a promise with the value wanted (outside of a generator)

Comment: Assuming he does want the return value of `getReply`, there is all reason to use `yield*`. Otherwise the `otherFun` will yield a generator object, which is rather useless.

Comment: When wanting to retrieve a single return value, just `yield` the call... There is really no need to use `yield*`.
I have not once used `yield*` in one of my projects (Node.js) and they all worked like I just described.

Comment: You probably are using `co` there which doesn't care what you yield.